# What are the differences between the Major anime and manga

Tags: major

While watching the major anime recently. I noticed quite a few differences in regards to the violence, which was greatly reduced in the anime. I also noticed that some team names were different. Such as the "Yokohama Marine Stars" being "Yokohama Blue Ocean" In the anime.

Are there any other significant changes in the anime as opposed to the manga?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picked up from wikipedia, [Major(Manga)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_(manga)#Plot_differences_between_the_manga_and_anime_version)

1. Team names

   - The "Yokohama Marine Stars" in the manga became "Yokohama Blue Oceans" in the anime.
   - The "Tokyo Shians" in the manga became "Tokyo Warriors" in the anime.
2. Many violent scenes (mostly physical fighting) in the manga were either greatly toned down, or completely removed in the anime.
3. The match between the Kaido Junior Varsity and Varsity teams

   - In the manga, Toshiya Sato's home run in the 7th inning was worth 2 runs, placing the JV team in the lead. The 8th and 9th innings quickly ended without incident or anyone scoring.
   - In the anime, Sato's home run was only a solo home run. Gorō gave up run in the 8th inning, but hit a 2-run home run off the Varsity team's ace pitcher and took back the lead. The 9th inning ended without either team scoring.
   - In the manga, Mayumura was never on the field. In the anime, he helped to make a hit in the 8th inning, to see if Shigeno has the ability to follow up with a game-winning home run, instead of having to rely on Sato in the 9th inning.
4. The birth of Chiharu and the retirement of Hideki Shigeno. In the anime, the birth of Chiharu and the retirement of Hideki Shigeno both happened a few years later than the manga timeline.
5. Ryoko Kawase

   - Kawase's plot elements in Season 2 and 3 of the anime were not present in the original manga. In the manga, there was no mention of her after the little league match. Kaoru Shimizu decided to go to Seishu after Komori's encouragement; Taiga pitched the 300 practice sliders to Gorō with his injured hand.
6. Ayane

   - When Gorō first moved back to Mifune, and was asking directions to Mifune East, the person who gave the wrong directions in the manga was Yamane (intentionally). In the anime it was Ayane (unintentionally).
   - Ayane's plot elements in Season 3 of the anime were not present in the original manga. In the manga, there was no mention of her after Gorō and Toshiya began school in Kaido.